# Can Logging statements affect Application Performance?

Tags: logging, enterprise-library

Can the Logger statements in Logging Application Block affect the performance of the application?

Comment: Similar post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1324699/compare-logging-application-block-in-enterprise-library-versus-log4net

Comment: Sure, it will call for server/client resources.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

You can't say anything more about it without pulling out a profiler and measuring it. There are so many variables it's impossible to make any general statements.